# Angularjs ng-grid using Grails JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-grid, gsp, grails-domain-class

Angular ng-grid data binding question

I have a Groovy/Grails application that has a domain “Grid” class for which I have registered a custom “marshaller” to produce the JSON that I can use for an Angularjs ng-grid..

Say “grid” is and instance of the Grid class,
“grid as JSON” produces the desired JSON.

I have a Grails/groovy controller that loads the data and returns the JSON:

```
def index() {
    def grid = Grid.first()
    grid as JSON
}
```

But I don’t know how to get this JSON data into the ng-grid in my GSP:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.gridOptions = ${grid};  // NEED HELP HERE !
    });
    </script>

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
```

I don't know how to get the data into $scope.gridOptions. When I look at what is   being generated with firebug, I see  $scope.gridOptions is

```
{&quot;columnDefs&quot;:[{&quot;field&quot;: ...
```

which is the encoded JSON data. (The quotation marks are encoded). What is the best way to pass JSON data between a Grails back end and ng-grid in a JSP?

Comment: Have you tried c:out JSTL tag with escapeXml=false

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the c:out JSTL tag from within the <script> tags, the encoding has already happened by the time its injected into the gsp. I would think that would have to be done on the groovy controller end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion Sridhar, I started looking for ways to un-escape JSON within GSP, and I found the answer here:

[how-to-render-json-properly-without-escaping-quotes-inside-a-gsp-script-tag](http://aruizca.com/how-to-render-json-properly-without-escaping-quotes-inside-a-gsp-script-tag/)

I need to use the g:applyCodec tag in my GSP:

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
     $scope.gridOptions = ${grid};
</g:applyCodec>
```

Comment: I do have a follow on problem however, where only the column definition data is being rendered: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959449/angular-js-ng-grid-using-grails-json-showing-column-headers-but-no-data)